# How to remove all line breaks and white space before and after a string in jquery

Tags: javascript, line-breaks

I have a string in jquery like following:

```
var str = "\n    \n        \n        \n            Michael Hartl\n        \n    \n";
```

but I want to fetch this string into this format as output

```
str = "Michael Hartl"
```

I tries with following functions:

```
str.replace(/\s*/," ")
```

but it results like

```
 " Michael Hartl


"
```

is there any other way in jquery to get the desired output?

Comment: `str.trim()`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim. Better still, fix the source of this problem to not allow junk to be entered.

Comment: `str.trim()` is the way, but if you had a string like `str = "word \n \n some more words \n \n bla bla"` and wanted to get rid of whitespace, `str.trim()` wouldn't work and you were close to your RegExp, the good call would be `str.replace(/\s+/g, " ")`

Comment: @ Rory McCrossan thank .trim() worked